# automatically checked the checkbox that corresponds to the given id in android

Tags: checkbox, android-checkbox

Can you help me with this one? How can I automatically checked the checkboxes that corresponds to the given value? What I am trying to do is allow the user to update the information he entered. I have customize spinner with checkbox that allow the user to select multiple value. The user will select values(multiple) on the customize spinner and will save the selection he do. My problem is, when the user click the edit button, the saved value from the checkbox that will be retrieved must be selected already. How can i do that? Thanks for anyone who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener on the button, and when he clicks it, in your handler for the button you can simply set the desired value on the associated checkbox.

something like this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v)
        {
            myBox.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if i have multiple checkbox that needs to checked?

Comment: Then you must somehow identify them. Since you didn't post some code, we can't know what you have or not have. You can check a many checkboxes as you want. And somehow you must know in your code, which checkbox belongs to which button. If you create the buttons beforehand, you know which button it is, and you can attach individual listeners to each of them. If you create the buttons dynamically, you must identify them within a generic listener, though I would prefer the first solution if possible.